# System.out.println doesn't work?

Tags: java, string, netbeans, system.out

When I write this in the main method:

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

Nothing is outputted on the output console. It just says "Build successful (total time: 0 seconds)". What's the problem?

Here is my full program:

```
package names;

  public class myName {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO code application logic here
      System.out.println("test");

  }
}
```

Here's the window after I debug the program:

```
Have no file for /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/jsfd.jar
Have no file for /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/laf.jar
Have no file for /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/sunrsasign.jar
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Did you execute the built executable?

Comment: How do you start the program? It looks like you're only building it.

Comment: You are debugging it, not running it. Right Click ==> Run File.

Comment: Mob's suggestion worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On netbeans right click and click run file. It would run. Seems like you're building the project, and not executing it.
Don't debug it. Run it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm nearly sure it's due to an IDE issue: the ant/build output is being redirected to a different place (not stdout) and you're seeing that "other place" as a "Console". Please let us know your IDE and as much code as you can.

Comment: He's using netbeans. See the tags

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it then. In netbeans, to run you can press F6 - http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html

Comment: I run the program and it doesn't output the string.

Comment: Sometimes the console pane is hidden.  Try clicking around the bottom part, it is there!